# Combination on jury selection

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

$20$ women (including Alice and Betty) and $12$ men show up for jury duty. In how many ways can you select a jury of at least $5$ women and at least $5$ men if one of Alice or Betty must be selected, but they cannot both be selected?

This is what I think: out of 12 men, choose 5, so that is a $_{12}C_5$, for women, you can only choose Betty or Alice, so there is $1$ choice there. If you have chosen one, the other cannot be chosen, so there are only $18$ women to choose from, and we need $4$ more women, so that is a $_{18}C_4$.

Is it correct that my final answer would be $C(12,5)*1*C(18,4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\binom{18}{4}\binom{2}{1}\binom{12}{7}+\binom{18}{5}\binom{2}{1}\binom{12}{6}+\binom{18}{6}\binom{2}{1}\binom{12}{5}$$
The first term standing for a choice of $4$ women out of the women where  Alice and Betty are excluded, of $1$ out of the couple Alice/Betty and $7$ out of all men.

The second term standing for a choice of $5$ women out of the women where  Alice and Betty are excluded, of $1$ out of the couple Alice/Betty and $6$ out of all men.

The third term standing for a choice of $6$ women out of the women where  Alice and Betty are excluded, of $1$ out of the couple Alice/Betty and $5$ out of all men.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of Alice or Betty gives $_2C_1=2$, not $1$.  Then you missed the "at least".  You have chosen exactly $5$ men and exactly $5$ women, so need to sum over the numbers of men and non-(Alice,Betty) women.

Comment: how do I sum over the numbers of men and women?

Comment: there are 7 men and 14 women left to choose, and a jury has 12 people, so should I multiply with 21C2

Comment: Criminal juries in the US have $12$ people, but we are not given that in the problem.  The number could be different, but let us assume that.  You can have 5 men and 7 women, 6 of each, or 7 men and 5 women.  Your calculation was for a jury of 10 with 5 men and 5 women.  You can't just multiply by $_{21}C_2$ because you will double count cases.  For example men 1,2,3,4,5 could be your first 5 and man 6 one of the last two.  Alternately you could have men 2,3,4,5,6 be the first 5 and man 1 in the last two.